# Regarding suggestion of best schema for a cassandra table?

Tags: cassandra

I want to have a table in Cassandra that has a partition key say column 'A', and a column say 'B' which is of 'set' type and can have up to 10000 elements in the set.

But when i retrieve a row from this table then the whole set is retrieved at once and because of that the JVM heap increases rapidly. So should i stick to this schema or go with other schema where 'A' is partition key and i make dynamic columns for each element in the set in my other schema say 'B1', 'B2' ..... 'B10,000'where each of this column is a clustering key.

Which schema is suited best and will give the optimal performance please recommend.

NOTE: cqlsh 5.0.1v

Comment: A few questions: Are the 10,000 elements a complete list? In other words does each row have up to 10k of the same elements ? Or is there a potential of 10k distinct elements for each row (i.e. row 1 has 10k elements, row 2 has 10k elements, but completely different 10k than row 1, etc.)? How often do you need to read/see the elements, and all of them? If it isn't often and it's the same list of elements for each row, you could create a separate table with the partition key being the element and use a "mask" column on your other table to flag which elements apply to the row. Just a thought

Comment: No, their will be almost all 10k distinct elements for each row as you mentioned in the second scenario, moreover insertions will be done often whereas reads will be executed infrequently.

Comment: waiting for your response sir.

Comment: Based off of what you're telling me, and everything I've read about collections, having a collection (list, map, set) of 10k is not a good idea. You could simply create two tables - one with everything but the collection, and the second table would have the same partition key as the first table, and the collection name as the clustering column. Turn the collection/list into rows. You'd have to loop through all rows to get the entire list, but should be quick as they have the same partition key (node). You can't query, say, by element name alone. Would always need partition key of primary table

Answer (score 0):

Based off of what you've described, and the documentation I've read, I would not create a collection with 10k elements. Instead I would have two tables, one with everything but the collection, and then use the primary key values of the first table, as the partition key columns of the second table; adding the element name (or whatever you can use to identify an individual element) as a clustering column.

So for a given query, if you wanted everything for a particular primary key value (including all elements), you'd query the first table with the primary key, grab whatever you need, then hit the second table as well, looping/fetching through all elements.

If the query only provides a filter on the partition key (not the primary key - i.e. retrieving multiple rows) , the first query would have to retrieve all columns that make up the primary key for each row, and then query the second table looping for all elements - nested loop here - one loop for each primary key record retrieved from the first table, and a second loop to grab all elements for each pk record.

Probably the best way to go with this. That's how I would probably tackle this.

Does that make sense?

-Jim